# jScrollPane: choose target to be scrolled and a separate scroller not in the hierarchy of the target?:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a Main-content DIV which I want to scroll using a scroller that replaces the window default scroller - I do not want the scroller to be attached to the target area

Can you do this with jScrollPane?

Thanks